# How to concatenate two html file bodies with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

**I need to concatenate the bodies of two html files into one html file, with a bit of arbitrary html as a separator in between.  I have code that used to work for this, but stopped working** when I upgraded from Xubuntu 11.10 (or was it 11.04?) to 12.10, probably due to a BeautifulSoup update (I'm currently using 3.2.1; I don't know what version I had previously) or to a vim update (I use vim to auto-generate the html files from plaintext ones). This is the stripped-down version of the code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup_original_1 = BeautifulSoup(''.join(open('test1.html')))
soup_original_2 = BeautifulSoup(''.join(open('test2.html')))
contents_1 = soup_original_1.body.renderContents()
contents_2 = soup_original_2.body.renderContents()
contents_both = contents_1 + "\n<b>SEPARATOR\n</b>" + contents_2
soup_new = BeautifulSoup(''.join(open('test1.html')))
while len(soup_new.body.contents):
    soup_new.body.contents[0].extract()
soup_new.body.insert(0, contents_both)
```

The bodies of the two input files used for the test case are very simple: `contents_1` is `\n<pre>\nFile 1\n</pre>\n'` and `contents_2` is `'\n<pre>\nFile 2\n</pre>\n'`.

I would like `soup_new.body.renderContents()` to be a concatenation of those two with the separator text in between, but instead all the `<`'s change into `&lt;` etc. - the desired result is `'\n<pre>\nFile 1\n</pre>\n\n<b>SEPARATOR\n</b>\n<pre>\nFile 2\n</pre>\n'`, which is what I used to get prior to the OS update; the current result is `'\n&lt;pre&gt;\nFile 1\n&lt;/pre&gt;\n\n&lt;b&gt;SEPARATOR\n&lt;/b&gt;\n&lt;pre&gt;\nFile 2\n&lt;/pre&gt;\n'`, which is pretty useless.

**How do I make BeautifulSoup stop turning `<` into `&lt;` etc when inserting html as a string into a soup object's body?  Or should I just be doing this in an entirely different way?** (This is my only experience with BeautifulSoup and most other html parsing, so I'm guessing this may well be the case.)

The html files are automatically generated from plaintext files with vim (the real cases I use are obviously more complicated, and involve custom syntax highlighting, which is why I'm doing it this way at all).  The full test1.html file looks like this, and test2.html is identical except for contents and title.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>~/programs/lab_notebook_and_printing/concatenate-html_problem_2013/test1.txt.html</title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Vim/7.3" />
<meta name="plugin-version" content="vim7.3_v10" />
<meta name="syntax" content="none" />
<meta name="settings" content="ignore_folding,use_css,pre_wrap,expand_tabs,ignore_conceal" />
<style type="text/css">
pre { white-space: pre-wrap; font-family: monospace; color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word }
body { font-family: monospace; color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff; font-size: 0.875em }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
File 1
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're trying to insert an HTML body as text, rather than as HTML, you can't stop BeautifulSoup from encoding the text, because the result wouldn't make sense otherwise. What you probably want to do is concatenate all children of the two bodies, as HTML, and then wrap that back up in a body tag?

Comment: As a side note, `''.join(open('test1.html'))` is making things overly complicated. You're breaking the file into lines just to join the lines back up into one big string. Why not just use the `read` method to get the file as one big string in the first place? (Plus, you really shouldn't leak files like this; use a `with` statement to close them.)

Comment: @abarnert The original version does use a `with` statement, I just wanted a one-liner for easier testing. Good point about `read` though.

Comment: As another side note, you really should consider upgrading to Beautiful Soup 4.x. Especially if you've just upgraded to a version you don't understand. Why bother learning all the ins and outs of 3.2.1 when it's obsolete and no longer supported and not that well documented, if you could just learn the current version instead?

Comment: @abarnert I didn't even know it was obsolete... I probably should. Is the answer going to be different with 4.x?

Comment: Actually, I wrote and tested my answer with 4.3.2 (and Python 3.4a), and then realized you were using 3.2.1 and went back and tested with the closest thing I had to that (and Python 2.7). Most 3.x code works in 4.x (although you _should_ upgrade any old-style names, like `findAll`, to `find_all`, I believe the intention is that they'll still work until 5.0), but the way it works under the covers is very different, so there may be some exceptions. See [Porting code to BS4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#porting-code-to-bs4) for details.

Comment: By the way, it's worth at least skimming through the entire main page of the docs, and reading all the parts that seem interesting. It's long and a bit rambling, but it's very clear, and by the time you get to the end, you'll understand how to do all kinds of things you didn't even know you wanted to do. :)

Comment: @abarnert I switched to 4, and it fixed a weird bug I was getting with the code. Thanks again! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [clone element with beautifulsoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057631/clone-element-with-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Trying to read the HTML as text just to insert it into HTML and fighting the encoding and decoding in both directions is making a whole lot of extra work that's very difficult to get right.

The easy thing to do is just not do that. You want to insert everything in the body of test2 after everything in the body of test1, right? So just do that:

```
for element in soup_original_2.body:
    soup_original_1.body.append(element)
```

To append a separator first, just do the same thing with the separator:

```
b = soup.new_tag('b')
b.append('SEPARATOR')
soup.original_1.body.append(b)
for element in soup_original_2.body:
    soup_original_1.body.append(element)
```

That's it.

See the documentation section [Modifying the tree](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-the-tree) for a tutorial that covers all of this.

Comment: I had trouble appending elements from one 'soup' to another. Appending with `copy.deepcopy(element)` helped.

Comment: Yes, there's PROBLEM with .append -- it removes the content from the source. So, if you are looping on input, say, 'for ii in soup.contents', then due to source entry ii being removed after first append, the loop will not work properly.

Comment: @EricSmith How do we define `soup`? is like like `soup = BeautifulSoup("<b></b>")`? Because I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'body'` when trying line: `soup.soup_original_1.body.append(b)`

Comment: @Newskooler it's just a typo, it should be `soup_original_1.body.append(b)` (with an underscore `_` instead of a dot `.`).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments to the answer by abarnert, there is a problem with append.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23058678/3709778) by Martijn Pieters♦ does the job.

From BeautifulSoup 4.4 onwards (released July '15), you can use:

```
import copy

document2.body.append(copy.copy(element))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with my html documents and looping through the elements. I found that BeautifulSoup just wasn't successfully parsing some of my HTML files. I ended up inserting a  tag around all of the elements inside the body tag:

```
<body><span id="entirebody">
:
</span></body>
```

This meant that all of the elements were encompassed in one span element and processed successfully. I want to dig into exactly what is happening when I don't do this but it is one way to get around problems you might encounter.

```
def insertSpan(htmlString):
    '''
    Insert a span tag around all of body contents:

    <body><span id="entirebody">....</span></body>
    '''
    subRe = re.compile(r'(<body>)(.*)(<\/body>)', re.DOTALL)
    htmlString = subRe.sub("\g<1><span id=\"entirebody\">\g<2></span>\g<3>",htmlString)
    return htmlString
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to post an functin here for reference, just because the prvious answer is no intact or with typo.

```
def merge_html(origin_doc, new_doc):
    soup_orgin_doc = bs4.BeautifulSoup(origin_doc,features="lxml")
    soup_new_doc  = bs4.BeautifulSoup(new_doc,features="lxml")
    b = soup_orgin_doc.new_tag('hr')
    # b.append('----')
    soup_orgin_doc.body.append(b)
    for element in soup_newdoc.body:
        soup_orgin_doc.body.append(copy.copy(element))
    return str(soup_orgin_doc)
```