# Beautiful Soup tag.contents item removed from different soup instance

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Somehow, if I take the contents of BeautifulSoup instance 'a' and insert it into instance 'b', it removes it from instance 'a.' Does this make sense?

```
a = BeautifulSoup('<p>0</p><p>1</p>')
b = BeautifulSoup('<p>2</p>')
additions = a.body.contents
while additions:
    b.body.insert(0, additions[-1])
```

'a' will end up like

```
<html><body></body></html>
```

'b' will end up like

```
<html><body><p>0</p><p>1</p><p>2</p></body></html>
```

Infinite loop aside, I'd expect 'a' to be unchanged. Am I just not reading the docs properly?

If I make a copy of 'additions' before the loop (something like `not_a_problem = additions[:]` ), the copy is untouched--meaning it will have `[<p>0</p>, <p>1</p>]` as its value

Comment: SWAG: This is not the code you are having problems with. The code you are actually having problems with uses `additions.pop()`.

Comment: I wish, but this is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access `a.body.contents` what you get back is not a list of strings but a list of BeautifulSoup's `Tag` objects.
For these `Tag` objects, BeautifulSoup uses similar semantics as HTML/XML DOM elements.

For example, a `Tag` object has a `parent` attribute, which contains the parent of that Tag in the current HTML (BeautifulSoup) document tree.

If you insert a Tag into a different BeautifulSoup document, the Tag where you insert it will become its new parent, and as it cannot keep its old parent, it is removed from the old document. That is because every Tag has one and only one parent.

It is just like any element of a tree can only be part of one tree, not two. Otherwise you would end up with situations where one Tag has a list of children, where some of the children have parent different from this tag, because they have been moved to some other tag. That might be confusing, at least. Thus the moment you insert a Tag in a different place, it gets detached from its old place.

For example in your case the `a` and `b` initially have tree structures like:

```
 a = Tag(html)         b = Tag(html)
       |                       |
    Tag(body)              Tag(body)
     /    \                    |
 Tag(p)   Tag(p)             Tag(p)
   |        |                  |
Str('0') Str('1')           Str('2')
```

(`Str` here is a shorthand for BeautifulSoups's `NavigableString` which loosely corresponds to a TextNode in DOM)

Now as you moved the second `p` tag from `a` into `b`' body via `b.body.insert(0, a.body.contents[-1])`, the structure for `b` now looks like:

```
  b = Tag(html)
       |
    Tag(body)
     /    \
 Tag(p)   Tag(p)
   |        |
Str('1') Str('2')
```

But then, the `parent` of this tag is now the body of `b`, and no longer that of `a`. If `a.body` still had the tag in its contents, you would have an **invalid** data structure like

```
   a = Tag(html) Tag(html) = b
       |             |
    Tag(body)    Tag(body)
     /    \      /      \
 Tag(p)    Tag(p)      Tag(p)
   |         |           |
Str('0')  Str('1')    Str('2')
```

That will not do; the `<p>1</p>` is contained in `b`, and if it would be still in the `contents` of `a.body`, then you would have the situation where one element in `a.body.contents` has a `parent` which is not `a.body.contents` itself.

Instead you end up (as you have correctly observed) with a data structure like:

```
 a = Tag(html)           b = Tag(html)
       |                       |
    Tag(body)              Tag(body)
       |                    /     \
     Tag(p)              Tag(p)  Tag(p)
       |                   |       |
    Str('0')            Str('1') Str('2')
```

As far as I can see that is not mentioned in the docs, maybe because the authors of the docs assumes that this is something "everybody knows".

If you want to copy Tag objects between document trees, you need to **clone** them instead; then you can end up with something like:

```
 a = Tag(html)         b = Tag(html)
       |                       |
    Tag(body)              Tag(body)
     /    \                 /     \
 Tag(p)   Tag(p)         Tag(p)  Tag(p)
   |        |              |       |
Str('0') Str('1')       Str('1') Str('2')
```

In that case look at [clone element with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057631/clone-element-with-beautifulsoup) how to do it. It is not that simple, as you need to make a deep copy of all the relevant data.

Comment: I guess one part of my confusion is that somehow the tags are being removed from the list generated by `a.body.contents`. Its really surprising that there is that much bookkeeping happening. I guess with your explanation of the why and some "Beautiful Soup knows how to clean up after itself" hand waving this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: The list in `a.body.contents` is not generated when you access it, it is an attribute of `a.body` created when the HTML string is parsed. This means any changes to the node structure of `a.body` are immediately reflected by this list. As you figured out by yourself, if you make a copy of that list, this is independent of the `a.body` and unaffected by moving Tag nodes around.