# Beautifulsoup: ValueError: Tag.index: element not in tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am converting ePub to single HTML files, so I need to concatenate the individual chapters into one HTML file. The are names "..._split_000.html" etc and I set up various structures to iterate over the ToC, generate directory names and so on.

I want to concat the HTML content of the individual parts with Beautifulsoup by appending the content of the body element of the following parts to the body of the first part. Only my code doesn't seem to work. "book" is an instance of the epub class of ebooklib. "docsfiles" is a dictionary with the names of the HTML files as a key and a list of files as one value among others:

```
def concat_articles(book, docsfiles, toc):
    articles = {}
    for doc, val in docsfiles.iteritems():
       firstsoup = False
       for f in val['files']:
           content = book.get_item_with_href(f).content
           soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
           if not firstsoup:
               firstsoup = soup
               continue
           body = copy.copy(soup.body)
           firstsoup.body.append(body)
       articles[val['id']] = firstsoup.prettify("utf-8")
    return articles
```

When I run this on my ePub, an error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract-new.py", line 170, in <module>
    articles_html = concat_articles(book, docsfiles, toc)
  File "extract-new.py", line 97, in concat_articles
    firstsoup.body.append(body)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 338, in append
    self.insert(len(self.contents), tag)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 291, in insert
    new_child.extract()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 235, in extract
    del self.parent.contents[self.parent.index(self)]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 888, in index
    raise ValueError("Tag.index: element not in tag")
ValueError: Tag.index: element not in tag
```

Actually I should unwrap() the so soup.body in the above code but the leads to another error, so I thought I would solve this first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange enough it works when I am using Martijn Peters' "clone()" method from [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057631/clone-element-with-beautifulsoup):

```
 body = clone(soup.body)
 firstsoup.body.append(body)
```

Why this works and "copy.copy()" doesn't, I have yet to figure out.

The complete working solution without duplication of the body tags looks like this:

```
       body = clone(soup.body)
       for child in body.contents:
          firstsoup.body.append(clone(child))
```

This also works when I am using "copy.copy()" in the first line but not when I replace "clone()" by "copy.copy()" in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late but I ran into a similar problem and found a solution that is more simple. Please turn the all the objects you extract with **BeautifulSoup** to a string, using the *str()* function.